# set all but one variable to false

Tags: python

I'm reading some text file and I using flag to append the data to the corresponding variables.
The text is like:

```
header_1

some text 
------------
-----------
some text 

header_2

some text 
------------
-----------
some text 

header_3

some text 
------------
-----------
some text
```

I'm reading line by line so:

```
if line=='header_1':
     flag_1 = True

if line=='header_1':
     flag_1 = False
     flag_2 = True

if flag_1:
     data_1.append(line)
elif flag_2:
     data_2.append(line)
```

What I want to avoid is to set again previous flags to false each time I get to the next part of the file, or do it in a more efficient way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not replace the flags with a single `state` variable

```
skip, h1, h2 = range(3)
state = skip
for line in lines:
    if line == 'header_1':
        state = h1
        continue
    elif line == 'header_2':
        state = h2
        continue

    if state == h1:
        data_1.append(line) # or whatever
    elif state == h2:
        data_2.append(line)
```

This is very flexible approach: if the flags are not mutually exclusive you can use a `set` of flags:

```
h4, h5 = range(4, 6)
for line in lines:
    if line == 'header_45':
        state == {h4, h5} 
        continue

    if state == {h5, h4}:
        do_smth()
    if h5 in state:
        do_smth_more()
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of hard-coding everything to individually-named variables, use a slightly broader condition and store your data in data structures:

```
result = []
for line in file:
    if line.startswith('header_'):
        result.append([])
    else:
        result[-1].append(line)
```

This will go through the file looking for headers. Whenever it finds one, it will add a new list to your overall result. Otherwise, it will add that line to the last available list.

Comment: Not sure the problem is specifically about 'header_' + a number. How about headers that have no patterns?

Comment: @Musen - There can be no program without a pattern, and it wouldn't make much sense to create headers like that anyway. Besides, the code in the question has headers with a pattern.

Answer (score 1):

How about using index instead of flags? say you have 2 kind of contents,

```
toAppend = [[], []]
flag = 0

for line in f:
  if line =='header_1':
     flag = 1
  elif line == 'header_2':
     flag = 2

  if flag:
     toAppend[flag - 1].append(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Build a dictionary, with headers as the keys and corresponding data lists as the values. Keep the last valid header in memory. So:

```
 dict_of_results = {}
 curr_header = ""
 for line in file:
     if line.startswith('header_'):
         curr_header = line
     if curr_header not in dict_of_results:
         dict_of_results[curr_header] = []
     dict_of_results[curr_header].append(line)
```

This form also allows the same headers appearing different locations in the text.

Comment: You can replace the `if curr_header not in dict_of_results:` by either `dict.get(key, default)` or by using a `defaultdict`